# Trouble using h:link to navigate to page with non-default suffix

Tags: jsf

I've got a JSF 2 application running on glassfish and have just installed the caucho
quercus PHP implementation. With just a little configuration I can successfully serve
.php files from the server:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What I'm not able to do is use h:link to navigate to a page that doesn't use the
default suffix (.xhtml). So when I have:

```
<h:link outcome="/hello.php"/>
```

I just get a WARNING: JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt48 in the server log (when the page is loaded), and no amount of fiddling with leading / seems to help. Is there a way to get h:link to work in this way or should I just use h:outputLink?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<h:link>` is for JSF navigation cases only, and thus indeed can't be used to navigate to other kind of resources, even when those are served by Servlets in the same application (like *.php in this case).

As you already suggested yourself, just use `<h:outputLink>`.

Comment: Thanks Arjan, I suppose it had to be that way but it's not obvious until you've tried it. I had planned to use h:link includeViewParams="true" to pass a CODI windowId, but instead just use outputLink with <f:param name="windowId" value="#{currentWindow.id}"/>, and it does the trick.